# How to initialize all values of array in structure in c

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I need to initialize all values of the array to 0. newCount->numbers[1] = {0} gives the error "expected expression". How would I go about this?

```
typedef struct count *Count;

struct count{
    int numbers[101];
    int totalCalls;
    int totalCallsEach[101];
};

Count create_Count(void){
    Count newCount = malloc(sizeof(struct count));
    newCount->numbers[101] = {0};
    newCount->totalCalls = 0;
    return newCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `memset` to set the values of the arrays to `0`.

```
memset(newCount->numbers, 0, sizeof(newCount->numbers));
memset(newCount->totalCallsEach, 0, sizeof(newCount->totalCallsEach));
```

**PS**

```
typedef struct count *Count;
```

is not a good `typedef`. Use:

```
typedef struct count Count;
```

or

```
typedef struct count *CountPtr;
```

Comment: It looks like `Count` is a type of `count *`...so `newCount` is a pointer

Comment: sadly, the OP used a typedef on the struct, where the typedef created Count as a pointer, so no additional '*' needed.  To me, this oops in the answer is just another reason to not use typedef's on structs.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the array intialized to all-bits-0 when you allocate the object, use `calloc` instead of `malloc`:

```
newCount = calloc( 1, sizeof *newCount );
```

This will also initialize the `totalCalls` and `totalCallsEach` members to all-bits-0.

If you want to set all the elements to any other value without looping through each, you'll need to use `memset`.

Style note: as a rule, it's not a good idea to hide pointers inside a `typedef`.  If anyone using an object of type `Count` needs to be aware of its pointer-ness (i.e., they need to use the `->` operator to access members instead of `.`), then it's better to do something like

```
typedef struct count Count;
...
Count *create_count(void)
{
  Count *new_count = ...;
  ...
}
```

IOW, make the pointer-ness of the object explicit in the declaration.

If you do not intend for anyone to directly dereference or access members of `Count` objects and provide an API for setting, getting, and displaying members like

```
myCount = createNewCount();
deleteCount( myCount );
x = getTotalCalls( myCount );
addCount( myCount, value );
printf( "myCount = %s\n", formatCount( myCount ) );
```

etc., then it's okay to hide the pointer-ness behind the typedef.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memset` ([doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/))

```
memset(newCount->numbers, 0, 101*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score -1):

struct count *newCount = (struct count *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct count))

Instead of malloc use calloc, it would create a memory of the size of "struct count" and initialize it to zero.

Comment: How does this add anything that [John Bode](http://stackoverflow.com/users/134554/john-bode)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29436879/369450) does not already address?